# sqlite update fails in android lollipop but works on kitkat?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

In kitkat I can run this code without any problems:

```
mDb = getDatabaseHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        mDb.beginTransactionWithListener(this);
        try {
            count = updateInTransaction(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            if (count > 0) {
                mNotifyChange = true;
            }
            mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            mDb.endTransaction();
        }
```

but on lollipop I get this weird error:

```
03-11 16:05:33.275    1947-2326/nl.afas.pocket E/SQLiteLog﹕ (11) database corruption at line 57126 of [9491ba7d73]
03-11 16:05:33.275    1947-2326/nl.afas.pocket E/SQLiteLog﹕ (11) statement    aborts at 54: [UPDATE Contact SET favorite=?,_id=? WHERE _id = ?]
03-11 16:05:33.275    1947-2326/nl.afas.pocket E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler﹕  Corruption reported by sqlite on database:     /data/data/nl.afas.pocket/databases/pocket.db
03-11 16:05:33.275    1947-2326/nl.afas.pocket E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler﹕ deleting the database file: /data/data/nl.afas.pocket/databases/pocket.db
03-11 16:05:33.278    1947-2326/nl.afas.pocket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-141
Process: nl.afas.pocket, PID: 1947
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed    object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/nl.afas.pocket/databases/pocket.db
        at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:520)
        at nl.afas.pocket.content.SQLiteContentProvider.update(SQLiteContentProvider.java:144)
```

the first error (database corruption) occurres at updateInTransaction

The second eror illigal state exception occurres at the mDb.endTransaction(); mDb is there already closed..

In KitKat no errors are thrown on exactly the same database.

Comment: Do you always get the same corruption error?

Comment: Yes always the same error...   03-16 11:12:24.526    2324-2409/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (11) database corruption at line 57126 of [9491ba7d73]
03-16 11:12:24.526    2324-2409/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (11) statement aborts at 54: [UPDATE Contact SET favorite=?,_id=? WHERE _id = ?]
03-16 11:12:24.526    2324-2409/? E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler﹕ Corruption reported by sqlite on database:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a database with an index in it.

Deleted the index, and the problem was solved.
(I'm running Lollipop emulator).

Comment: thanks. it was working on android 6 marshmallow but failing on android 5 lollypop `database corruption`. But, after dropping the indexes, it worked on both.

Comment: how to delete indexes? about what indexes you are talking?